# Header of a word file via Delphi XE5

Tags: delphi, ms-word, header, delphi-xe5

I want to adjust the header of a word file generated with Delphi such that the first line is bold and the second line is not bold.

But since the string for the header is one string I cannot seem to get the second line normal.

How can I ensure that the second line in the header of a word file is not bold?

```
procedure Print;
var v:olevariant;
    procedure HeaderandFooter;
    var adoc:olevariant;
    begin
    v.Selection.Font.Bold:=1;

    adoc:= v.Documents.Add(EmptyParam, EmptyParam);
    adoc.Sections.Item(1).Headers.Item(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text :=
    'Line one of the header which is bold' +#13
    + 'Line two of the header which is normal';
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me using D7 and Word 2007, but should work fine with later versions of both.

I'm not sure how you arrived at your code, but I created the part of mine which inserts and formats the header by recording a macro to do it in MS Word, then "translating" it to Delphi, editing out some superfluous "fluff" on the way.  My code uses "late binding" (i.e. it accesses the MS Word objects via variants) but I think it would be straightforward to re-write it using the interfaced objects defined in the Word2000 unit (i.e. early binding).

```
uses ... ComObj, Word2000 ...;

procedure TForm1.MakeDocWithHeader;
var
  MSWord,
  Document : OleVariant;
  AFileName,
  DocText : String;
begin
  MSWord := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
  MSWord.Visible := True;

  Document := MSWord.Documents.Add;
  //  First, insert some text into the new document's body
  DocText := 'Hello Word!';
  MSWord.Selection.TypeText(DocText);

  //  Next, make the Header window the active one
  if MSWord.ActiveWindow.View.SplitSpecial <> wdPaneNone then
      MSWord.ActiveWindow.Panes(2).Close;
  if (MSWord.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdNormalView) or (MSWord.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdOutlineView) then
      MSWord.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type := wdPrintView;
  MSWord.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView := wdSeekCurrentPageHeader;

  //  Now, add three lines of text to the header
  MSWord.Selection.TypeText( Text:='Header line 1');
  MSWord.Selection.TypeParagraph;
  MSWord.Selection.TypeText( Text:='Header line 2');
  MSWord.Selection.TypeParagraph;
  MSWord.Selection.TypeText( Text:='Header line 3');

  //  Next, make the first line bold
  MSWord.Selection.HomeKey( Unit:=wdStory);
  MSWord.Selection.EndKey( Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend);
  MSWord.Selection.Font.Bold := True;
  MSWord.Selection.HomeKey (Unit:=wdLine);

  //  Finally, return the caret to the main body of the document
  MSWord.Selection.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToNext, Count:=1);

  AFileName := 'd:\aaad7\officeauto\worddocwithheader.docx';
  Document.SaveAs(AFileName);
  ShowMessage('Paused');
  Document.Close;
end;
```

**Update:**  I've added a Delphi implementation of Cindy Meister's solution.

```
procedure TForm1.MakeDocWithHeader2;
var
  MSWord,
  Document,
  rngDocument,
  rngHeade,
  Headers : OleVariant;
  DocText : String;
begin
  MSWord := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
  MSWord.Visible := True;

  Document := MSWord.Documents.Add;
  DocText := 'Hello Word!'#13;

  // Following is a Delphi adaptation of the implementation in Cindy Meister's answer.
  rngDocument := Document.Content;
  rngDocument.Text := DocText;

  Headers := Document.Sections.Item(1).Headers;
  rngHeader := Headers.Item(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range;

  rngHeader.Text := 'Header Line 1'#13;
  rngHeader.Font.Bold := True;
  rngHeader.Collapse(wdCollapseEnd);
  rngHeader.Text := 'Header Line 2';
  rngHeader.Font.Bold := False;
end;
```

Comment: It works in XE5 when I remove the Unit:= references in your code.

Comment: In that case, your unit must already be Using another unit which contains the Word wdXxxx constants.

Comment: Btw, if this answer works for you, please feel free to "accept" it by clicking the tick symbol next to its top left.  Accepting an answer indicates to future readers that it is useful and increases the rep of the person who wrote the answer and yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I can't give you Delphi code, but I can give you VBA code that takes a slightly different approach than what Martyn proposes.

One drawback of the macro recorder is that it mimics users actions, rather than working directly with the object model. This is usually slower, causes screen flicker AND is less reliable because the user *could* click somewhere on the screen, thus changing the Selection.

Working with the RANGE object is much more reliable, especially since it avoids SeekView, which is definitely buggy. Here's an example which you can compare; note that the approach is more similar to the original than the proposed answer:

```
Dim rngDoc as Word.Range
Dim rngHeader as Word.Range

Set rngDoc = Document.Content
Set rngHeader = Document.Sections(1).Headers(Word.WdHeaderIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
rngDoc.Text = DocText
rngHeader.Text = "Header Line 1" & Chr(13)
rngHeader.Font.Bold = -1
rngHeader.Collapse Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd£
rngHeader.Text = "Header Line 2" & Chr(13) & "Header Line 3"
rngHeader.Font.Bold = 0
```

The "trick" with this approach is to "collapse" the Range to its end-point after applying the formatting and before continuing with the new text.

Comment: Actually, I far prefer your implementation to my initial one as more robust and concise, so +1 for that.  I've taken the liberty in adding a Delphi translation of it to my answer.  Translating it was actually a good bit trickier than I was expecting, so I thought I might as well record the result for future readers.

Comment: @MartynA Interesting to see the "translation" :-)  Is there an incorrect closing parenthesis: Document.Sections.Item(1).Headers);   ? And thanks very much for the upvote.

Comment: Oops!  I missed that when I simplified that line after adding it to my answer, thanks for picking it up.

Comment: @MartynA: thanks for translating Cindys code. It works perfectly. 
CIndy: That's a very nice implementation! I agree that range objects are more reliable. I upvoted your post.